# I want to do INVISIBLE on SubActivity with the button on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

**SubActivity cannot INVISIBLE the button in MainActivity I tried to use intent, but I'm not sure.**

it SubActivity java code

try to INSIBLE the resetB button in Sub Activity

```
public class SubActivity extends Activity {

    Button resetH, resetH2;
    Button resetB, miC;


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);

        resetH = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetH);
        resetH2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetH2);
        resetB = findViewById(R.id.resetB);
        

        resetH.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resetB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        

        resetH.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                resetB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });



        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I used intent, but I can't move the button

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is not clear. Generally one `Activity` cannot manipulate `View`s in another `Activity. Please edit your question and more clearly describe what you want to do.

Comment: Questioner. We've solved this problem.
https://www.masterqna.com/android/102691/mainactivity%EC%97%90-%EC%9E%88%EB%8A%94-%EB%B2%84%ED%8A%BC%EC%9D%84-subactivity%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C-%EB%B3%B4%EC%9D%B4%EC%A7%80-%EC%95%8A%EA%B2%8C-%EB%A7%8C%EB%93%A4%EA%B3%A0-%EC%9E%88%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4